# Problema com BETWEEN entre datas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Estou precisando de uma luz para uma questão, tenho um sistema de filtragem de dados(busca) onde tenho de buscar por duas datas Inicial e Final. Sendo que possuo essas duas colunas no banco, então quando executo a busca escolho qual coluna desejo filtrar. Ambas as colunas são do tipo `date`

Então meu sql ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT * FROM negocio WHERE data_inicial BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-30' ORDER BY data_inicial DESC
```

Porem nos resultados não retorna apenas datas dentro do período selecionado, por exemplo retorna dados da data `2017-02-20` e de campo vazios que ainda não possui sua data definida.

---

```
CREATE TABLE negocio (
  negocio_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  data_inicial date default NULL,
  data_final date default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (negocio_id)
);
```

Como falei são dos campos, mas a questão é retornar o período as datas dentro do período selecionado pelo usuário. No caso o usuário pode selecionar se busca em `data_inicial` ou `data_final` e por qual ordem ele gostaria de exibir os dados.

Comment: A consulta que você usa é a mesma da pergunta?

Comment: Suas datas estão salvas com horas:minutos:segundos no banco ou não?

Comment: Pode colar aqui a estrutura da tabela? Às vezes é campo com nome diferente.

Comment: A consulta é em um período de 30 dias como corrigi na pergunta :( postarei a tabela abaixo

Comment: A data `2017-02-20` é da coluna que está sendo filtrada? Se escolheu `data_inicial` então está vindo essa data neste campo?

Comment: Sim a data `2017-02-20` está na mesma coluna filtrada. Correto retornando a data neste campo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem 2 campos de datas, o `BETWEEN` vai fazer o intervalo dentro de `data_inicial` da forma que você está fazendo. Se vc quiser o intervalo entre data_inicial e data_final, faça dessa forma:

```
SELECT * FROM `negocio` WHERE data_inicial >= '2017-01-01' and data_final <= '2017-01-30' ORDER BY data_inicial DESC
```

Comment: Sim, essa foi a minha primeira opção porém não é o que preciso no momento. O objetivo aqui é saber quais negócios tem vencimento(`data_final`) em um determinado período ou quais foram contratados em um determinado mês(`data_inicial`). Mais seu exemplo me um luz que posso testar.

`SELECT * FROM negocio WHERE data_inicial >= '2017-01-01' and data_inicial <= '2017-01-30' ORDER BY data_inicial DESC`